# Appending a wordlist to URLS to make a webrequest

Tags: python

-I have a wordlist where each entry is printed on a separate line in a .txt file.
-I am adding the wordslists entries onto the end of a url (nsip is listed below as a placeholder)

I am trying to take each URL and and make web requests BUT when I print i.e. full_url[0] it just gives me the whole the whole wordlist appended to the url. When I use type it tells me that full_url is a list so I am unsure as to why each element is not accessible.

any ideas how to make it so as I can easily make requests

```py
lines = [
    '.bash_history',
    '.bashrc',
    '.cache',
    '.config',
    '.cvs',
    '.cvsignore',
    '.forward',
    '.git/HEAD',
    '.history',
    '.hta',
]

for line in lines:
    full_url = []
    full_url.append('https://google.com/' + line)
    print(full_url[0])
    print(type(full_url))
```

Comment: Could you post part of the *common.txt* file?

Comment: .bash_history
.bashrc
.cache
.config
.cvs
.cvsignore
.forward
.git/HEAD
.history
.hta

Comment: All printed on separate lines in the actual file btw

Comment: I created a [mre] for you, so others can copy-paste the code and don't need your common.txt file. Output is the same. However, I'm still not sure what you're actually asking... Maybe you can clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `full_url = []` before the loop:

```
filename = '/Users/Desktop/common.txt'
nsip = 'google.com'
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    full_url = []
    for line in file:
        linefinal = line.rstrip()
        full_url.append("https://" + nsip + '/' + linefinal)

print(full_url)
```

which gives:

```
['https://google.com/.bash_history', 'https://google.com/.bashrc', 'https://google.com/.cache', 'https://google.com/.config', 'https://google.com/.cvs', 'https://google.com/.cvsignore', 'https://google.com/.forward', 'https://google.com/.git/HEAD', 'https://google.com/.history', 'https://google.com/.hta']
```

Is that what you were after?